# How to pass cucumber tag as parameter and update in test runner file before perform execution in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, cucumber, test-runner

i am new for Jenkins and want to pass a parameter like cucumber tag from jenkins and it should update in test runner file dynamically and then should start execution. Please share me code or screenshots.

Comment: What kind of project you are working on? For example, Freestyle or Pipeline

Comment: its maven project.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to UnknownBeast, with Cucumber v6 and onwards you can no longer use `cucumber.options` with a command line like string. Instead you'll have to use individual properties.

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="(@cucumber or @gherkin) and not @salad"
```

Supported properties are:

```
cucumber.ansi-colors.disabled=  # true or false. default: false                     
cucumber.execution.dry-run=     # true or false. default: false 
cucumber.execution.limit=       # number of scenarios to execute (CLI only).  
cucumber.execution.order=       # lexical, reverse, random or random:[seed] (CLI only). default: lexical
cucumber.execution.strict=      # true or false. default: false.
cucumber.execution.wip=         # true or false. default: false.
cucumber.features=              # command separated paths to feature files. example: path/to/example.feature, path/to/other.feature  
cucumber.filter.name=           # regex. example: .*Hello.*
cucumber.filter.tags=           # tag expression. example: @smoke and not @slow 
cucumber.glue=                  # comma separated package names. example: com.example.glue  
cucumber.plugin=                # comma separated plugin strings. example: pretty, json:path/to/report.json
cucumber.object-factory=        # object factory class name. example: com.example.MyObjectFactory
cucumber.snippet-type=          # underscore or camelcase. default: underscore
```

From 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/core#properties-environment-variables-system-options

Comment: Hello M.P. could you please let me where I can see the changelog?

Comment: Thanks @M.P. Korstanje for the replay, but my requirement is from jenkins in a label text box ill write tag name that will automatically add in shell script and while building a job dynamically pass tag name in test runner class to perfrom execution. Kindly share me with screenshot if you have this project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the test cases associated to Tags, this is how we specify : mvn test -Dcucumber.options=”–tags @tag Name”

So what you can do, set the parameters in the Jenkins job and then you can execute the test script with the above maven command. So the tag name will come from the parameter that you have set in the Jenkins job.

Comment: Thanks, @UnkinwnBeast, I want to pass cucumber parameter using a text box where user enters tag it refers shell script and before performing execution it has to update that tag in test runner file.

Comment: Here everything will be same in the runner file. When pass this parameter it overrides the  configuration that you have added in the runner file. So I believe that you can do the execution of maven goals with the shell script too

Comment: @vishalbha did you manage to do what you need? I was also looking for this solution.

Comment: I have entered `$ mvn test -Dcucumber.options=”–tags @smoketest”` and get error
```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "@smoketest”". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: ...
```